# Using an array in a different method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, scope, return

I'm new to programming, but I've taken a course on python and have been learning C# on my own. I do realize this question has been answered, but I was not able to understand the answer.

EDIT: Sorry, I'll try to explain my question in more detail. In the new method, I want to create a 3D array with all the values from the 2D array CPU. So I want CPU to be passed into the new method so I can copy that into the new 3D array and then modify its contents.

So I have a method....

```
public string pickRoles(string name)
```

and I have this array

```
string[,] CPU = new string[6, 2]
            {
                { (names[index]), (cpu_1_role) },
                { (names[index]), (cpu_2_role) },
                { (names[index]), (cpu_3_role) },
                { (names[index]), (cpu_4_role) },
                { (names[index]), (cpu_5_role) },
                { (names[index]), (cpu_6_role) },
            };
return CPU[6, 2];
```

How do I copy the array into a new method so I can use it there? And when should I create a new class instead of having a bunch of methods? Please explain answers in detail for me. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need to prefix your questions with 'C#', that's what the tags are for.

Comment: what answer did you find, can you link it?

Comment: You can pass the array to a message, but "copying" into an array isn't clear.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Incidentally, `CPU[6, 2]` will be out of bounds, because the indices are zero based.  `CPU[5, 1]` is the last element.

Comment: Also, ask specific and clear questions, try to keep your questions related per post (fewer == better)

Comment: Do you need to 'copy' the array to a new method? Or pass it by reference? In this 'new' method, are will you make changes to the array? Do you want those changes to persist to the caller?

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing, but if you want to return the array and use it in another method, change the return type of `pickRoles` to `string[,]`:

```
public void Foo()
{
    string[,] CPU = pickRoles("Foo");
}

public string[,] pickRoles(string name)
{
    string[,] CPU = new string[6, 2]
    {
            { (names[index]), (cpu_1_role) },
            { (names[index]), (cpu_2_role) },
            { (names[index]), (cpu_3_role) },
            { (names[index]), (cpu_4_role) },
            { (names[index]), (cpu_5_role) },
            { (names[index]), (cpu_6_role) },
    };
    return CPU;
}
```

Comment: it looks like you declared CPU in main?

Is that a better way to format? I have a bunch of variables declared in the same method its used and I have to make a bunch of comments to find anything.

But If I changed "return CPU[6,2];" to "return CPU;"
I get an error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[*,*]' to 'string'"

Comment: That's because you need to change the return type of the method to `string[,]` instead of just `string`. As for the declaration, for the sake of the example I declared the array locally within the `pickRoles` method, and returned the array to the calling method ('Foo`).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I copy the array into a new method so I can use it there?

Do you mean how to return the array?

You must write the right return type:

```
public string[,] pickRoles(string name)
```

And to return the whole array you must return the pointer in this case:

```
return CPU;
```

Comment: Ah this seems like what I was looking for. But I do not understand anything about pointers except that they reference to the memory location of a variable, and not the variable itself?

Comment: Yes, It references the memory location of the array. You can do `string[,] newArray = pickRoles("Example");` and here `newArray ` references `CPU`. So you're not passing every value in the array but both are pointing on the same location of memory and they take the same data.

Answer (score 0):

If you method is declared within a class and your array is a member of the class, then you method should be able to directly access that member. If they are not in the same class, then you can pass the array as a parameter to your method. If you method is supposed to produce an array, then you can return it by changing the return type.

Incidentally, I'm guessing that what you are trying to do is fine the cpu_*x*_role associated with a string name. Is that correct? If that is the case, you might want to look at the Dictionary rather than a 2D array.

Comment: Actually in the original method, the program has a list of names, and stores it into CPU[x,0]. Then it determines cpu_x_role by a switch case and stores that into CPU[x,1]. Now I'm trying to figure a way to store a bunch of dialogue[by dialogue I mean console.writeline();] that each role can execute based on its role.